# When is it recommended to use the PyCharm IDE install of Python and when is it not?

Tags: python, pycharm

The following folder appears to have Python installed on my Windows machine after installing PyCharm and creating a new project.  Please note that I did not install the standalone Python.  Is this a true Python installation or is this just how PyCharm interacts with Python?  When is it appropriate to interact with Python using this folder (from command line or PyCharm)?  When is it recommended to use the standalone Python install?

```
C:\Users\MacGyver\PycharmProjects\Example01\venv\Scripts>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is E0C6-8347

 Directory of C:\Users\MacGyver\PycharmProjects\Example01\venv\Scripts

06/16/2020  03:03 PM    <DIR>          .
06/16/2020  03:03 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/16/2020  03:03 PM             2,306 activate
06/16/2020  03:03 PM               983 activate.bat
06/16/2020  03:03 PM            18,454 Activate.ps1
06/16/2020  03:03 PM               368 deactivate.bat
06/16/2020  03:03 PM            97,169 easy_install-3.8.exe
06/16/2020  03:03 PM            97,169 easy_install.exe
06/16/2020  03:03 PM            97,160 pip.exe
06/16/2020  03:03 PM            97,160 pip3.8.exe
06/16/2020  03:03 PM            97,160 pip3.exe
06/16/2020  03:02 PM           420,936 python.exe
06/16/2020  03:02 PM           419,912 pythonw.exe
              11 File(s)      1,348,777 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,830,408,224,768 bytes free

C:\Users\MacGyver\PycharmProjects\Example01\venv\Scripts>
```

Also, I did not follow the directions here.  I simply installed PyCharm.  So this documentation seems incorrect.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/quick-start-guide.html#meet

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a Python [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments)?

Comment: PyCharm created a virtual environment for the project.  But the PyCharm website says you need to go to Python.org and install Python as well.  I did not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current structure, you have created a virtual environment for your project to start with. This virtual environment contain the python, which  will be accessible when
your activate the environment by go in `venv/bin` and type `activate`.

Note in this, you can only use python when you activate the environment for this project.Also this is not global system wise environment i.e. by typing python in terminal it wont open python shell it will show unknown python command, as environment variable not set.

Also for the folder name it seem you are learning the language. So it would be better if you create a single `venv` for all your learning process or you can use local system installed python, where python is also set in system variable.

*When is it recommended to use the standalone Python install?*

not a universally acceptable, but i use standalone python, when i want to test out new libraries, do come competitive programming, do some sample python stuff, or when i am learning something related to core python or visualization programming.

in case you are working in a project, small or a large (lets say a calculator or **scraping**) then it is better to create a venv like your current one, and start working on that python environment.

to install python, you can go to python.org or anaconda.com. both are same just anaconda provide other features like visualization,IDE (spyder), better modules dependency and can be setup easily.

Comment: it is recommended that if you working on a project then it is better to create a separate  python environment so that you keep check of the python version you are using in the project (3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8) and all the packages/modules you are installing during the project. Now lets you are working on two project with different area (web and desktop app say) and you working on different version of python, or a module which require a specific python version then using virtual env is recommended. else if your project both working on same python version and you dont need to maintain the package

Comment: then you can use standalone python and installed everything in it. in later stage you want to separate the project by different venv then u still can do that, just require a little effort that which package belong to which project .. u can use `pip list` to get all package and sperate package then

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a true python installation. Obviously, when you created the project, you have chosen the python interpreter with a new virtual environment. Pycharm then downloads and install the virtual environement into the project folder, with the most recent python version. You can interact with it as with any normal python installation. It is not only appropriate, it is the recommended way to work in Pycharm.